# How to check a value in nested array for Required Attribute for hiding a field in Redux Framework?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, redux-framework

I want to disable the below section based on the value coming from sorter(hm-homepage-layout). I know that we can't pass nested array as an argument in the 'required' attribute array.. Is there any way I can hide the section based on the value $opt-name["hm-homepage-layout"]["enabled"] == "Hero Component"

```
array(
'id'       => 'hm-hero-section',
'type'     => 'section',
'title'    => __( 'Hero Section', 'hm' ),
'subtitle' => __( 'Details about the Hero Section', 'hm' ),
'indent'   => true,
'required' => array( 'hm-homepage-layout["enabled"]["hm__hero]', 'equals', 'Hero Component' )
)
```

Any other suggestions to hide sections based on sorter values are welcome as well.